# How to make 1GB Android App with Cordova

Tags: android, cordova

I have a web app for Cordova that needs to store about 1 gigabyte in the www area (.png images, for direct access from url's). The targets are Android and iOS.

I have tested with ~240MB and ~650MB total size.

At ~240MB, it works, although it puts it all in one .apk with is not suitable for Play Store distribution.

With 650MB, it creates one huge unaligned .apk. Then it blows up in zip-align.

How can I build it correctly with Cordova?

[Build system: Mac Mini w/Yosemite]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When the app is bigger than the size allowed by google play you have to use expansion packages

There is a plugin for expansion files
https://github.com/agamemnus/cordova-plugin-xAPKreader

And here you have a tutorial about how to use it
https://iphonedevlog.wordpress.com/2014/12/12/adding-an-android-apk-expansion-file-to-a-cordova-project/